# What's wrong? Why pointer stays constant?

Tags: c

I learn C programming for a while and I had to create a program, which contains a function void hello() displays word 'Hello :)' and the number, how many time the function hello() was called. The code bellow displays 'Hello' but the number of function calling stays constant. I just want to know, what's wrong and why it isn't working as it should.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

void hello(int *p_number);
int number = 1, i;
int* p_number = number;

for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++){
    hello(&p_number);
    printf("Number in cyclus = %d\n", number);
    number++;
}

return 0;
}

void hello(int *p_number){
    printf("number of calling = %d, Hello :)\n", *p_number);
}
```

Comment: `int* p_number = number;` should be `int* p_number = &number;`

Comment: Although it's probably more idiomatic and simpler to skip `p_number` completely and just write `hello(&number);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need

```
int* p_number = &number;
```

and

```
hello(p_number);
```

at the calling site.

i.e. set `p_number` to the *address* of `number`. And do turn up the warning level on your compile *and read them*! There is a fair amount of redundancy in maintaining a pointer in `hello`; presumably this is for an exercise?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
void hello(int *p_number);

int main(void) {

    int number = 1, i;
    int *p_number = &number;

    for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        hello(p_number);
        printf("Number in cyclus = %d\n", number);
        number++;
    }

    return 0;
}

void hello(int *p_number) {
    printf("number of calling = %d, Hello :)\n", *p_number);
}
```

Set the pointer to point at the address of number, pass pointer address to function.